# WPF Setting the default style on a TextBlock overrides the style for a Label

Tags: wpf, styles, default, font-size, textblock

Setting the default style on a TextBlock causes the style in the Label and other controls to be set as well. This only happens if you put the styles in the Application resources, when I place the style in the Window resources everything is fine.

I have also found that the VS 2008 Designer and XamlPadX display the Label as you would expect but the problem only occurs if you execute the application in real life.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication.App"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
   <Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
               <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8"/>
           </Style>

           <Style x:Key="Title" TargetType="Label">
               <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32"/>
           </Style>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.Window1"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Height="300"
       Title="Window1"
       Width="300">
   <StackPanel>

       <TextBlock Text="TextBlock No Style" Style="{x:Null}"/>
       <Label Content="Label No Style" Style="{x:Null}"/>

       <TextBlock Text="Default TextBlock"/>
       <Label Content="Default Label" Style="{StaticResource Title}"/>

   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The code above displays:

```
TextBlock No Style - Default font size (As you would expect)
Label No Style - Size 5 font size (How did this happen?)
Default TextBlock - Size 5 font size (As expected by my style)
Default Label - Size 5 font size (How did this happen?)
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes, that's to be expected; look at the default template for Label, it's just an indented TextBlock. Styles are *inherited*, so the Label will set the FontSize to 32, but then the TextBlock's style will override that. If you just had , it'd be 5pt as well.

**Edit:** So the way I'd solve this, is to create a dummy subclass (i.e. a class which changes nothing) of TextBlock called NormalText, then style that; this way you won't accidentally pick up other TextBlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try to change the label's content like:

```html
  <Label>
             <Label.Content> 
                 <TextBlock 
                  Text="{Binding Content}"    
                  FontSize="30"></TextBlock> 
             </Label.Content>
   </Label>
```